# Android - OnDraw() Method never gets called

Tags: android, rendering, game-engine

I'm new to programming in android and I can't understand why the OnDraw() method in my renderer doesn't get called as invalidate() is called. The final set background resource does get called however. There are 2 classes, Game.java and Renderer.java. It seems that the invalidate call does not have time to get processed during the loop in game.

## Game.Java

```
public class Game extends Activity 
{
    Level currentLevel;
    private static List<Entity> _renderList = new ArrayList<Entity>();


    public void StartLevel(View view)
    {   
        System.out.println("I HAVE STARTED THE LEVEL!");
        // Hide the play button
        Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_game);
        playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Load the level
        currentLevel = new Level1(this);
        // Create the initial entities

        // Add the entities to the screen   
        List<Bitmap> bitmapList;
        bitmapList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        Bitmap enemy = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.enemy);
        bitmapList.add(enemy);
        System.out.println("CREATING RENDERER!");
        Renderer renderer = new Renderer(this, _renderList, bitmapList);
        renderer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.beachbackground);
        setContentView(renderer);
        System.out.println("STARTING TRAVEL!");
        while (currentLevel.GetDistTravelled() < currentLevel.GetDist())
        {
            Retrieve();
            currentLevel.AddDistance(1);
            System.out.println("DISTANCE +1!");
            renderer.RenderFrame(_renderList);
            System.out.println("RENDER LEVEL FRAME!");
            try 
            {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(50);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("SET BACKGROUND!");
        renderer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
    }

    public List<Entity> GetRenderList()
    {
        return _renderList;
    }

    private void Retrieve()
    {
        // get the array
        Entity[] enemies;
        enemies = currentLevel.CheckSpawn();
        if(enemies != null)
        {
            // parse the array into entities
            int length = enemies.length;
            System.out.println(length);

            // remember to Get enemy strings
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                // add them to our array
                _renderList.add(enemies[i]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

## Renderer.java

```
class Renderer extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{
    PanelThread _thread;
    List<Entity> _renderList = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    List<Bitmap> _bitmapList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    public Renderer(Context context, List<Entity> renderList, List<Bitmap> bitmapList)
    {   
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        _bitmapList = bitmapList;
    }

    public void RenderFrame(List<Entity> renderList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < renderList.size(); i++)
            {
                _renderList.add(renderList.get(i));
            }
        invalidate();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        Paint paint = null;

        // Draw enemies

        if(_renderList.size() != 0 && _renderList != null)
        {
            int size = _renderList.size();
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(_bitmapList.get(_renderList.get(i).GetBitmapID()), _renderList.get(i).GetX(), _renderList.get(i).GetY(), paint);
            }
        }
    }

        // position the train on the screen in the appropriate place    



    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        setWillNotDraw(false); //Allows us to use invalidate() to call onDraw()

        _thread = new PanelThread(getHolder(), this); //Start the thread that
        _thread.setRunning(true);                     //will make calls to 
        _thread.start();                              //onDraw()
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        try 
        {
            _thread.setRunning(false);                //Tells thread to stop
            _thread.join();                           //Removes thread from mem.
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    class PanelThread extends Thread
    {
        private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
        private Renderer _renderer;
        private boolean _run = false;

        public PanelThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Renderer renderer) 
        {
            _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            _renderer = renderer;
        }


        public void setRunning(boolean run) 
        {
            _run = run;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            Canvas c;
            while (_run) 
            {     
                c = null;

                try 
                {
                    c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (_surfaceHolder)
                    {
                    //Insert methods to modify positions of items in onDraw()
                    postInvalidate();

                    }
                } 
                finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Any help on solving this problem would be very grateful. If anymore info is needed just ask.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have the same error like you. But i have found that. But i don't known clearly about that.

but you can try

add the attribute **android:background** to your layout.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. That function won't do anything different in our case. However we have now fixed ours. What we did was in our renderer we are using the Canvas type, Canvas has its own thread so if you use the canvas thread you can get it to successfully update your screen. You'll have to do some research on this as I am not sure of the details as I wasn't the one who found out this solution.